# C++ Minimax issue for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c++

I'm trying to apply a simple minimax algorithm to this tic tac toe game so I can later extend it for othello, but I'm having trouble figuring out what is specifically wrong with my code. I realize similar questions have been asked, but I'm having issues implementing it with my code in particular. Hopefully it isn't too hard to follow without the other classes provided. Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been trying to figure out the issue for around two days now and I really need a fresh pair of eyes.

Edit: The exact issue I'm having is that the minimax function is often not returning the correct value and so it selects the wrong moves. For instance, sometimes in a state where the player is about to win it will return -10 as if it thinks it can win even though if the algorithm was working correctly it should make the player win the next turn unless blocked. It rarely blocks because it isn't interpreting the player's moves correctly I think. The actual evaluation function, however, returns the correct values for each individual state.

```
#include "Minimax.h"
#include <iostream>


Board *Minimax::GetNewBoard(Board *board, char playerPiece, char compPiece)
{
    this->playerPiece = playerPiece;
    this->compPiece = compPiece;

    return MinimaxFunction(board, false);
}

Board *Minimax::MinimaxFunction(Board *board, bool playerTurn)
{
    if (TerminalTest(board)) return board;

    Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);

    vector<Board*> boardChoices = GenerateMoves(board, playerTurn);

    int minValue = 999;
    int maxValue = -999;

    for (vector<Board*>::iterator it = boardChoices.begin(); it != boardChoices.end(); it++)
    {
        if (playerTurn)
        {
            int currentValue = GetMax(*it, playerTurn);
            cout << "Max: " << currentValue << endl;
            if (currentValue > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = currentValue;
                *newBoard = *(*it);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int currentValue = GetMin(*it, playerTurn);
            cout << "Min: " << currentValue << endl;
            if (currentValue < minValue)
            {
                minValue = currentValue;
                *newBoard = *(*it);
            }

        }
        (*it)->PrintBoard();
    }

    return newBoard;
}

//something wrong with getmin or getmax? it doesn't recognize when it should lose
//possibly not choosing best move for player so it chooses wrong enemy move
//results in -10 (thinks it will win) for turns where it is about to lose,
//but evaluate function returns correct values for individual states
int Minimax::GetMax(Board *board, bool playerTurn)
{
    if (TerminalTest(board))
    {
        //cout << "max: " << Evaluate(board) << endl;
        return Evaluate(board);
    }
    Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);
    vector<Board*> boardChoices = GenerateMoves(board, playerTurn);

    int maxValue = -999;

    for (vector<Board*>::iterator it = boardChoices.begin(); it != boardChoices.end(); it++)
    {
        int currentValue = Evaluate(*it);

        if (currentValue > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = currentValue;
            *newBoard = *(*it);
        }
        //cout << "current value for max function: " << currentValue << endl;

    }
    cout << "value: " << Evaluate(newBoard) << endl;
    newBoard->PrintBoard();

    return GetMin(newBoard, !playerTurn);
}


int Minimax::GetMin(Board *board, bool playerTurn)
{
    if (TerminalTest(board))
    {
        //cout << "min: " << Evaluate(board) << endl;
        return Evaluate(board);
    }

    Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);

    vector<Board*> boardChoices = GenerateMoves(board, playerTurn);

    int minValue = 999;

    for (vector<Board*>::iterator it = boardChoices.begin(); it != boardChoices.end(); it++)
    {
        int currentValue = Evaluate(*it);

        if (currentValue < minValue)
        {
            minValue = currentValue;
            *newBoard = *(*it);
        }
        //cout << "current value for min function: " << currentValue << endl;

    }
    cout << "value: " << Evaluate(newBoard) << endl;
    newBoard->PrintBoard();

    return GetMax(newBoard, !playerTurn);
}

//Gets value for state
//10 is win
int Minimax::Evaluate(Board *board)
{
    int value = 0;

    if (board->IsFull()) value = 0;

    //checks win for
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ((board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 1) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 2) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) == playerPiece) ||
            (board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(1, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(2, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) == playerPiece))
        {
            value = value + 10;
        }
    }

    if ((board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(2, 2) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) == playerPiece) ||
        (board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(2, 0) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) == playerPiece))
    {
        value = value + 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ((board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 1) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 2) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) == compPiece) ||
            (board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(1, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(2, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) == compPiece))
        {
            value = value - 10;
        }
    }

    if ((board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(2, 2) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) == compPiece) ||
        (board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(2, 0) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) == compPiece))
    {
        value = value - 10;
    }

    return value;
}

//checks if someone won or the board is full (tie)
bool Minimax::TerminalTest(Board *board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ((board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 1) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) == board->GetSlot(i, 2) && board->GetSlot(i, 0) != ' ') ||
            (board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(1, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) == board->GetSlot(2, i) && board->GetSlot(0, i) != ' '))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if ((board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) == board->GetSlot(2, 2) && board->GetSlot(0, 0) != ' ') ||
        (board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(1, 1) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) == board->GetSlot(2, 0) && board->GetSlot(0, 2) != ' '))
    {
        return true;
    }


    if (board->IsFull()) return true;

    return false;
}

bool Minimax::ValidMove(Board *board, int x, int y)
{
    if (board->IsSlotEmpty(x, y))
        return true;

    return false;
}

vector<Board*> Minimax::GenerateMoves(Board *board, bool playerTurn)
{
    vector<Board*> boardChoices;
    for (int x = 0; x < board->GetWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < board->GetHeight(); y++)
        {
            char currentPiece;
            if (playerTurn) currentPiece = playerPiece;
            else currentPiece = compPiece;

            if (ValidMove(board, x, y))
                {
                    Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);
                    newBoard->SetSlot(x, y, currentPiece);

                    boardChoices.push_back(newBoard);
                }
        }
    }

    return boardChoices;
}
```

Edit again:
After some feedback and looking at the solution at [Return bestMove in minimax algorithm for tictactoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523050/return-bestmove-in-minimax-algorithm-for-tictactoe)

I've changed the following functions, but it still makes some of the wrong decisions and loses:

```
Board *Minimax::MinimaxFunction(Board *board, bool playerTurn)
{
    //if (TerminalTest(board)) return board;

    Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);

    int i = 0;

        if (playerTurn)
        {
            i = GetMax(board, playerTurn, newBoard);
        }
        else
        {
            i = GetMin(board, playerTurn, newBoard);
        }


    cout << "i is " << i << endl;
    return newBoard;
}

int Minimax::GetMax(Board *board, bool playerTurn, Board *newBoard)
{
    if (TerminalTest(board))
    {
        //cout << "max: " << Evaluate(board) << endl;
        return Evaluate(board);
    }
    //Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);
    vector<Board*> boardChoices = GenerateMoves(board, playerTurn);

    int maxValue = -999;

    for (vector<Board*>::iterator it = boardChoices.begin(); it != boardChoices.end(); it++)
    {
        //int currentValue = Evaluate(*it);
        Board *bestBoard = new Board(*board);

        int currentValue = GetMin(*it, !playerTurn, bestBoard);

        if (currentValue > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = currentValue;
            *newBoard = *(*it);
        }

        //cout << "current value for max function: " << currentValue << endl;
        //(*it)->PrintBoard();

    }
    //cout << "value: " << Evaluate(newBoard) << endl;
    //newBoard->PrintBoard();

    //return GetMin(newBoard, !playerTurn);
    return maxValue;
}


int Minimax::GetMin(Board *board, bool playerTurn, Board *newBoard)
{
    if (TerminalTest(board))
    {
        //cout << "min: " << Evaluate(board) << endl;
        return Evaluate(board);
    }

    //Board *newBoard = new Board(*board);

    vector<Board*> boardChoices = GenerateMoves(board, playerTurn);

    int minValue = 999;

    for (vector<Board*>::iterator it = boardChoices.begin(); it != boardChoices.end(); it++)
    {
        //int currentValue = Evaluate(*it);
        Board *bestBoard = new Board(*board);
        int currentValue = GetMax(*it, !playerTurn, bestBoard);

        if (currentValue < minValue)
        {
            minValue = currentValue;
            *newBoard = *(*it);
        }
        //cout << "current value for min function: " << currentValue << endl;
        //(*it)->PrintBoard();
    }
    //cout << "value: " << Evaluate(newBoard) << endl;
    //newBoard->PrintBoard();

    //return GetMax(newBoard, !playerTurn);
    return minValue;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what it your exact problem (compile error? wrong output? etc.)

Comment: I have added an edit with the exact problem, thanks.

Comment: Have you written any [unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)?

Comment: you don't seem to be implemanting MinMax. You appear to just doing a heuristic deep first search for a terminal state. Min Max only evaluates terminal states. For other states it just either gets the min or the max of states resulting from possible moves. Try using GetMin or GetMax where you have evaluate in your GetMax/Min functions and return your min/maxValue.

Comment: My understanding was that it should currently only be returning the value of a terminal state and evaluating each of the possible moves to find the min/max value of that move. It keeps calling getmax or getmin on whatever possible move turns out to be the highest/lowest out of those options. Is that not right?

Comment: I tried implementing what I believe you were suggesting, but that only seems to result in an infinite loop. I changed currentValue to equal GetMin/GetMax and then return min/maxValue. It seems closer to the implementation I see at the link below so you might be on the right track, but I'm not sure what the issue is now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523050/return-bestmove-in-minimax-algorithm-for-tictactoe

Comment: Got it working partially, but it still doesn't always select moves correctly.