# Implementing Minimax Algorithm with two tasks

Tags: minimax

I have a major problem in my minimax algorithm. I have to implement a game, where is a player and an AI player. Both of them can step up,down,right,left diagonal and after that they have to block a cell, where the other player can't step (ofc, where the other player stays is a blocked cell and can't block that one, and you can't block an already blocked cell too). I wrote a little minimax algorithm for that, but for a strange thing the AI can't decide the best root.

```
struct Position
{
    int x, y;
} MaxP, MinP;

int k = 2;
char board[10][10];
int currentPlayer = 2;

//Here are my global variables, MaxP is the AI, and MinP is the player.
```

I set the cells B (as blocked) around my table.
The minimax calculation algorithm:

```
int nyertesErtek(int result) //return a winning value, if result=1 Ai Wins, if result=2 Player Wins, if result=0, then the game it's still going
{
    if (result == 1) return 10;
    if (result == 2) return -10;

}


int minimax(char pBoard[10][10], int depth, bool isMaximizing)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (isMaximizing==true)
    {
        int checkX[8] = { -1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1 };
        int checkY[8] = { 0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1 };

        bool lephetMax = false;
        bool lephetMin = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (pBoard[MaxP.x + checkX[i]][MaxP.y + checkY[i]] != 'B')
            {
                lephetMax = true;
                break;
            }

        }


        if (lephetMax == false)
        {
        result = 2;
        }

    }

    if (isMaximizing == false)
    {
        int checkX[8] = { -1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1 };
        int checkY[8] = { 0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1 };

        bool lephetMin = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (pBoard[MinP.x + checkX[i]][MinP.y + checkY[i]] != 'B')
            {
                lephetMin = true;
                break;
            }
        }


    if (lephetMin == false)
        {
            result = 1;
        }

    }



    if (result != 0) //ha nem terminal state
    {
        //cout << "Resultra jutott"<<endl;
        //cout << "---------------->Kovetkezne a: " << isMaximizing << " Result=" << result << " NyeresErtek=" << nyertesErtek(result) <<" depth="<<depth<< "<---------------"<<endl;
        //printBoard();
        return nyertesErtek(result);
    }


    int checkX[8] = { -1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1 };
    int checkY[8] = { 0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1 };

    if (isMaximizing)
    {
        int bestScore = -INT_MAX;
        int szabadX;
        int szabadY;

        for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
        {
            if (pBoard[MaxP.x + checkX[l]][MaxP.y + checkY[l]] != 'B')
            {

                int oldMaxPX = MaxP.x;
                int oldMaxPY = MaxP.y;

                MaxP.x = MaxP.x + checkX[l];
                MaxP.y= MaxP.y + checkY[l];


                pBoard[MaxP.x][MaxP.y] = 'B';
                pBoard[oldMaxPX][oldMaxPY] = 'o';


                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                    {

                            if (pBoard[i][j] != 'B')
                            {
                                szabadX = i;
                                szabadY = j;

                                pBoard[szabadX][szabadY] = 'B';

                                //cout << "Maximizing, depth=" << depth << endl;
                                //printBoard();

                                int score = minimax(pBoard, depth + 1, false);

                                pBoard[szabadX][szabadY] = 'o';

                                if (score > bestScore)
                                {
                                    bestScore = score;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                pBoard[MaxP.x][MaxP.y] = 'o';
                pBoard[oldMaxPX][oldMaxPY] = 'B';



                MaxP.x = oldMaxPX;
                MaxP.y = oldMaxPY;
                }

            }
        return bestScore;
    }
    else
    {

        int bestScore = INT_MAX;
        int szabadX;
        int szabadY;



        for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
        {
            if (pBoard[MinP.x + checkX[l]][MinP.y + checkY[l]] != 'B')
            {
                int oldMinPX = MinP.x;
                int oldMinPY = MinP.y;


                MinP.x = MinP.x + checkX[l];
                MinP.y = MinP.y + checkY[l];



                //pBoard[MinP.x + checkX[l]][MinP.y + checkY[l]] = 'B';

                pBoard[MinP.x][MinP.y] = 'B';
                pBoard[oldMinPX][oldMinPY] = 'o';

                //cout << "Minimizing depth= " << depth << endl;
                //printBoard();


                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                    {
                        if (pBoard[i][j] != 'B')
                        {
                            szabadX = i;
                            szabadY = j;

                            pBoard[szabadX][szabadY] = 'B';



                            int score = minimax(pBoard, depth + 1, true);
                            //pBoard[MinP.x + checkX[l]][MinP.y + checkY[l]] = 'o';
                            pBoard[szabadX][szabadY] = 'o';

                                if (score < bestScore)
                                {
                                bestScore = score;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                pBoard[MinP.x][MinP.y] = 'o';
                pBoard[oldMinPX][oldMinPY] = 'B';


                MinP.x = oldMinPX;
                MinP.y = oldMinPY;
                }
            }
        return bestScore;
    }
}
```

And moving the AI is in this function:

```
void bestMove() {
    int checkX[8] = { -1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1 };
    int checkY[8] = { 0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1 };

    int bestScore = -INT_MAX;
    Position move;
    int AIBlockX, AIBlockY;
    int szabadX;    
    int szabadY;

    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++)
    {
        if (board[MaxP.x + checkX[l]][MaxP.y + checkY[l]] != 'B')
        {
            int oldMaxPX = MaxP.x;
            int oldMaxPY = MaxP.y;

            MaxP.x = MaxP.x + checkX[l];
            MaxP.y = MaxP.y + checkY[l];

            board[MaxP.x][MaxP.y] = 'B';
            board[oldMaxPX][oldMaxPY] = 'o';


            for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
                {
                    if (board[i][j] != 'B')
                    {
                        szabadX = i;
                        szabadY = j;

                        board[szabadX][szabadY] = 'B';
                        int score = minimax(board, 0, false);
                        cout << endl << "Ennyi a score amit kaptam pech=" << score << endl;

                        board[szabadX][szabadY] = 'o';



                        if (score > bestScore)
                        {
                            bestScore = score;
                            move.x = MaxP.x;
                            move.y = MaxP.y;
                            AIBlockX = szabadX;
                            AIBlockY = szabadY;

                            cout << "BESTMOVE: " << move.x << " " << move.y << " bestscore= " << bestScore << endl;
                        }


                    }
                }
            }

            board[MaxP.x][MaxP.y] = 'o';
            board[oldMaxPX][oldMaxPY] = 'B';

            MaxP.x = oldMaxPX;
            MaxP.y = oldMaxPY;
        }
    }


    board[move.x][move.y] = 'B';
    board[MaxP.x][MaxP.y] = 'o';
    MaxP.x = move.x;
    MaxP.y = move.y;
    board[AIBlockX][AIBlockY] = 'B';
    currentPlayer = 2;
}
```

I think my main problem is something in the minimax function: when I check where the player can go -> and after that all the possible blocking moves. And in that triple for when I rewrite the best score with the current score I can't return the value directly because I have to check other possible moves in the firs for iteration.
So after all (:D) my question is that how can I save the best move after the cell blocking was done and return that to my AI to step there? Thank you for you answer. :)

ps:I'm sorry if this post is too long, but I thought to fully understand my problem, you also have to see the algorithm part.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a lot of code and a bit unclear--how does the game work exactly? The player blocks the cell they are standing in, or any cell? If any cell, then the game sounds like sort of variant of [game of the amazons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_the_Amazons) except with kings instead of queens and only 2? The game details are pretty important and examples are helpful. Thanks for the clarification. As for saving the best MM move, you could use a class to maintain state. When you find a new best move, set the class var and ultimately return that using a wrapper function.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you for your fast response. Sorry if it was unclear, but basically a player can take a step (but only up/down/righ/left/diagonal) and after the step has to choose any cell in the matrix which he wants to block (as i mentioned above only if it's a cell is not blocked, so it's free and the other player is not on that cell). The one who can't make the next step (all the cells around him are blocked) has lost the game. Can you share more details about your idea, or how exactly implement it? I thought about an array and return the last element of it maybe?

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention. Both of the players starts at the middle of the matrix, and the matrix size has to be odd

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So is your problem "how do I return the best value" or is there something game-specific going wrong beyond that? Maybe take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523050/return-bestmove-in-minimax-algorithm-for-tictactoe) which applies to tic tac toe but deals with the same basic algorithm. It seems folks are preferring returning a struct pair of evaluation value and best move for a position.

Comment: Unfortunately the mistake is not in the minimax function, I debugged it in certain positions/blocks and in every way has adequate depths and nodes are calculated correctly. Something is not working at my bestStep function maybe, my guess is that it can't create the relations in the tree. The link you sent before is a quiet complex from the perspective of the datastructure, so I could not managed to implement it. I think I will rewrite my code completely and make it in a more OOP way, because in this way I can't really know where the program went wrong :/